# applying css to dijit button

Tags: css, dojo

I have the following HTML and CSS:

```
<button id="myBtn" dojoType="dijit.form.Button">Testing</button>

#myBtn {
    margin-left: 100px;
}
```

The CSS is supposed to push the button in `100px`. But since `dijit` applies some extra layers of HTML around the button, the button gets a `100px` padding.

[JSbin to show the problem](http://jsbin.com/ejoma)

**edit:** Found one (not IE6-compatible) solution:

```
[widgetid=myBtn] { margin-left: 100px; }
```

Comment: why is it not IE6 compatible? can you post your code in another JSbin so we can maybe debug it.

Comment: @Kau-Boy IE6 doesn't support attribute selectors in CSS...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

see above :-)  Surround with a DIV and use that DIV in your static CSS.

I think decorating with HTML may actually be a simpler solution than trying to bake more into the widget or the widget's template.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of applying the style by ID, do it through a class.

Stylesheet:

```
.myBtn { margin-left: 100px; }
```

Code:

```
<button class="myBtn" dojoType="dijit.form.Button" id="myBtn">Testing</button>
```

http://jsbin.com/ejoma/2

Comment: Doesn't work when creating widget imperatively (your example is declarative).

Answer (score 1):

In this case you should not add the margin-left to the button itselft but to the additional HTML araound the button that is created. Try this:

```
.dijitLeft{
    margin-left: 100px;
}
```

But this will indeed add a margin to every button. If you don't want that, add the margin to the parent span using JavaScript after the additional HTML was created.

Comment: That's such a pain, though. Isn't there any option in the parser that I can tell to move the `id` attribute to the top-most layer when it's applying HTML elements around the original one?

Comment: No unfortunately not. There is even no change to get an element with CSS that has some specific child node. But as you already use a JS framework it should be no problem to assign the CSS with this framework. But as I don't know the dojo framework I can't tell you how the function is called.

Comment: dojo.style() will assign styles dynamically.  Perhaps you could also put your button in an HTML element with an ID or class and use that in a static style rule.

Comment: @peller: moving the button into an elemten with an ID is an excellent idea! Than the button will not "jump" after using dojo.style().

Comment: @peller Yeah, that idea did cross my mind, I was just hoping there was a better and less "useless" way of doing it. I would now have to surround every button with a "useless" `<div>` or `<span>`... But that's better than using javascript on all buttons.

Comment: @peirix: using another element around the button will also fix it for IE6. And as far as I know IE6 supports some attribute selectors (at least an equal selector) but not on custom attributes.

Comment: Yup, and it also fixes another problem I had with dijit widgets, using the HTML5 `data-` attributes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053713/keep-data-attributes-in-dijit-widgets  
@peller if you write your comment as an answer, I'll set it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Inline style is working.

```
<button id="myBtn" dojoType="dijit.form.Button" style="margin-left:100px">Testing</button>
```