# keep data-attributes in dijit widgets

Tags: dojo, custom-data-attribute

I've started using the HTML5 `data-` attributes in my application, but when this is applied to an element that is a dijit widget, it disappears.

```
<button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" data-id="5">Number 5</button>
```

Is dojo actually parsing this and keeping it somewhere? Or is it just removed completely because dojo isn't HTML5 compliant?

Comment: I think it's the latter.  Properties are handled explicitly by the parser, based on what's in the widget prototype.  Let's see what bill has to say on your ticket: http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/11325  He's out until next week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By applying the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052299/applying-css-to-dijit-button), I was also able to keep the custom `data-` attributes on the surrounding element.